# android don't lose Fragment when back button is pressed

Tags: android-fragments, onbackpressed, data-loss

The user create and add some Fragments to the Activity identified by a tag. I noticed that on pressing the back button the Fragment is destroyed. How can I don't lose all the fragments when the back button is pressing? So that I can navigate without recreating all the time the fragments. I'm asking for a properly way to do this, indeed for now my idea is to override the onBackPressed() and save the Fragment in a List global variable of Fragments before destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

While creating the fragment's instead of FragmentTranscation.replace, use  FragmentTranscation.addTobackStack() to add the fragment to backstack and do nothing onBackPressed.

On pressing back button FragmentTranscation will take care of navigating to the previous fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in the onBackPressed() function.

```
if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
} else {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```